# Xcode: Template doesn't show

Tags: xcode, templates

I have tried to create an Xcode template, it's located at this path:

```
/Users/rob/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/TestTemplate.xctemplate
```

In this folder:

```
___FILEBASENAME___.swift
```

I checked the path in Xcode Preferences > Locations:

[image]

But when I try to create a new file in Xcode, this template doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode has both project and file templates. You need to create a `File Templates` folder inside the `Templates` folder to store your file templates. You should also create a group folder inside the `File Templates` folder to store your file templates so there's a section for the templates in the New File Assistant.

```
/Users/rob/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/My Templates/TestTemplate.xctemplate
```

Where `My Templates` is the name of the group holding the file template. You can name the group anything you want.